# Is jdbc by itself compatible with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'd like to know if jdbc by itself is compatible with mysql or do I have to intsall something extra? I was told it is not compatible and that I'd have to use a different database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does.

You have to use the correct mysql jdbc driver and that's it!

Some useful links:

Little old but still helpful:

[Using JDBC with MySQL, Getting Started](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381)

Official reference:

[Official JDBC Driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)

[JDBC reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

You have to look at your specific version.

MySQL belogs to Sun Microsystems now after all

[Using MySQL from Java](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is a **specification** for Java/database interaction.  As a specification it's compatible with almost every DB.  However, you need a JDBC compliant driver written for your database.  Googling "jdbc driver {databasevendor}" should get you an the right track.